# Converting characters to ciphered ASCII values

Tags: python, list, string-function

I want to take a word from a user and convert it into the separate characters' ASCII values, putting them in a list and seperating them by a hyphen. It then adds the user input for 'number' to each seperate ASCII value in the list.

If I input:

> python3 stringFunctions.py hideIt hello 6

it should output:

> [109-106-113-113-116]

Here is my program:

```py
def cipherIt(word, number):

    vals = []
    for ch in word:
        vals.append(ord(ch))
    new_vals = []
    for val in vals:
        val = str(val + number)
        new_vals.append(vals)
    return new_vals
```

The output is

```py
[[104,101, 108, 108, 111]],
[[104,101, 108, 108, 111]],
[[104,101, 108, 108, 111]],
[[104,101, 108, 108, 111]],
[[104,101, 108, 108, 111]],
[[104,101, 108, 108, 111]]
```

When I use:
`python3 stringFunctions.py cipherIt Hello 6`

it puts the ASCII values of "hello" in a list together, but instead of adding five, it prints five instances of the list.

Comment: I think you meant `new_vals.append(val)` not `new_vals.append(vals)`. `vals` is the list you made, `val` is the string. Let this be a lesson in picking descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to maintain one list that stores all of the integer values -- using `new_vals` isn't necessary:

```py
def cipherIt(word, number):
    vals = []
    for ch in word:
        vals.append(ord(ch) + number - 1)
    return '[' + '-'.join(str(val) for val in vals) + ']'

print(cipherIt("hello", 6)) # Prints [109-106-113-113-116]
```

Comment: Ok, I see where I went wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add "number" value to the ord() value then this might be what you want.

```
def cipherIt(word, number):
    vals = []
    for ch in word:
        vals.append(str(ord(ch) + number))
    text = '-'.join(vals)
    return text
```

You can, of course, add '[ ]' to the string if that's desired.

```
text = '[' + text + ']'
```